# Test the existence of a Teradata table and create the table if non-existent

Tags: ruby, hudson, jruby, teradata, rubymine

Our Continuous Inegration server (Hudosn) is having a strange issue when attempting to run a simple create table statement in Teradata.

This statement tests the existence of the max_call table:

```
 unless $teradata_connection.table_exists? :arm_custom_db__max_call_attempt_parameters
  $teradata_connection.run('CREATE TABLE all_wkscratchpad_db.max_call_attempt_parameters AS (SELECT * FROM arm_custom_db.max_call_attempt_parameters ) WITH NO DATA')
end
```

The `table_exists?` method does the following:

```
def table_exists?(name)
        v ||= false # only retry once
        sch, table_name = schema_and_table(name)
        name = SQL::QualifiedIdentifier.new(sch, table_name) if sch
        from(name).first
        true
      rescue DatabaseError => e
        if e.to_s =~ /Operation not allowed for reason code "7" on table/ && v == false
          # table probably needs reorg
          reorg(name)
          v = true
          retry 
        end
        false
      end
```

So as per the `from(name).first` line, the test which this method is performing is just a simple select statement, which, in SQL, looks like: `SELECT TOP 1 MAX(CAST(MAX_CALL_ATTEMPT_CNT AS BIGINT)) FROM ALL_WKSCRATCHPAD_DB.MAX_CALL_ATTEMPT_PARAMETERS`

The above SQL statement executes perfectly fine within Teradata SQL Assistant, so it's not a SQL syntax issue. The generic ID which our testing suite (Rubymine) uses is also not the issue; that ID has select access to the arm_custom_db.

The exeption which I can see is being thrown (within the builds console output on Hudson) is 
`Sequel::DatabaseError: Java::ComTeradataJdbcJdbc_4Util::JDBCException`. Since this execption is a subclass of DatabaseError, the exception shouldn't be the problem either.

Also: We use `unless` statements like this every day for hundreds of different tables, and all except this one work correctly. This statement just seems to be a problem.

The complete error message which appears in the builds console output of Hudson is as follows:

```
[2015-01-07T13:56:37.947000 #16702] ERROR -- : Java::ComTeradataJdbcJdbc_4Util::JDBCException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 13.10.00.17] [Error 3807] [SQLState 42S02] Object 'ALL_WKSCRATCHPAD_DB.MAX_CALL_ATTEMPT_PARAMETERS' does not exist.: SELECT TOP 1 MAX(CAST(MAX_CALL_ATTEMPT_CNT AS BIGINT)) FROM ALL_WKSCRATCHPAD_DB.MAX_CALL_ATTEMPT_PARAMETERS
Sequel::DatabaseError: Java::ComTeradataJdbcJdbc_4Util::JDBCException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 13.10.00.17] [Error 3807] [SQLState 42S02] Object 'ALL_WKSCRATCHPAD_DB.MAX_CALL_ATTEMPT_PARAMETERS' does not exist.
```

I don't understand why this specific bit of code is giving me issues...there does not appear to be anything special about this table or database, and all SQL code executes perfectly fine in Teradata when I am signed in with the same exact user ID that is being used to execute the code from Hudson.

Comment: May I suggest that you replace `SELECT TOP 1...` with `SELECT 1 FROM ALL_WKSCRATCHPAD_DB.MAX_CALL_ATTEMPT_PARAMETERS WHERE 0=1;' for your existence test. It will be less resource intensive than `TOP` + `MAX`. On the surface, the error itself is pretty straightforward, the object you are querying isn't in the database you specified. But it appears you can query the table directly using SQLA. Is that correct?

Comment: Changing the built in method of the Sequel gem is not possible, nor a good idea, in this case.

Comment: Ah. In that case I understand.

Comment: But the issue is that the table_exists? Method is supposed to run that sequel script, and of our fails ( because the table doesn't exist) then it rescues the exception that is thrown and then returns false to its caller. Then my unless statement would be aware that the table is non existent.